How to extract a substring from a string by removing a specified word that can appear anywhere?
I have a string, for example, "John Doe", where one word is a known keyword, and the other is the remaining part that I need to extract. Given a string like "John Doe", I know the keyword, e.g., "Doe", and I want to extract the other word, "John".
I initially tried this approach:
String input = "John Doe";
String keyword = "Doe";
String result = input.replace(keyword, "").trim();

This works fine if the keyword is at the end of the string. However, it doesn't handle cases where the keyword might be at the beginning or somewhere in the middle. For example, if the input is "Doe John" or if the keyword is part of another word, like "Johnathan", it fails. In the case of "Johnathan Doe", using "John" as the keyword incorrectly returns "athan Doe".
I need a way to reliably extract the remaining part of the string when the keyword is known, regardless of its position in the string, and to treat the keyword as a whole word.
I also tried this:
String input = "John Doe";
String receiver = "Doe";
String[] parts = input.split("\\b" + receiver + "\\b");
String result = "";
if (parts.length > 1 && !parts[1].trim().isEmpty()) {
    sender = parts[1].trim();
}
else if (parts.length > 0 && !parts[0].trim().isEmpty()) {
    sender = parts[0].trim();
}   

But it's a long way. Sure there's a shorter way to do this

This regex might be a good place to start? But play around with it to make sure it does what you're looking for. (.*)\b.*?John.*?\b(.*)

@dimitri08 The code you wrote would turn "Doe John" into just John which is what you appear to want. But you say that it is not what you want. Either [A] edit the question and fix this part, or [B] explain why function("Doe John") -> "John" isn't what you're looking for. Until you clarify that, this does not appear answerable.

You apparently don't want to extract anything.  What you want is to simply delete a word and leave the remainder.  I would try something like this. The regex caters to a keyword surrounded by blanks or a keyword at the beginning of the string or at the end.
String[] s = {"Johnathan", "John Doe"};
 String keyWord = "John";
 for (String str : s) {
    str = str.replaceAll("(?:^|\\s+)"+keyWord+"(?:$|\\s+)", "");
    System.out.println(str);
 }

prints
Johnathan Doe
Doe

